# Should admin account be in the same user class as a customer?

Tags: grails, spring-security, authorization

I learn Grails and Spring Security plugin.

I don't know how to design sample web application with two layers: customer can view product and categories and order a product (if he/she is registered and logged in) and admin who can logged in to admin panel where he/she can manage categories and products (CRUD). My question is: should all users (admin and customer)  be in one User class? I suppose that all apllication (catalog and admin panel) should be secured by Spring Security plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the Spring Security plugin then the default behavior assumes all users are instances of the same class. You can distinguish between an administrator and a customer by checking what's returned by the `roles` property of the user class.

The plugin provides a service and various Grails tags that you can use to figure out whether a user is an administrator, a cusomer, is authenticated, etc.

Answer (score 1):

yes all users should be one class. and then you assign roles to each user. for example a user can have the ROLE_USER, and another user can have the ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN